# Image is not shown in django template,

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a django template where i send an image actually its for an email.It only works when i keep the whole url like abc.com/images/a.png .
i have sent he image like this:

```
{
 'picture':picture.url
}
```

This is the code for template that i am using for email template:

```
<img src="{{picture}}" alt="image" width="200" height="200" >
```

Am i missing something? as it only works when i keep the whole url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build an absolute URL you can use `request.build_absolute_uri(picture.url)` in your view.